# Set distance between widget and its title (text) in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app which diplays three `colourInput()` buttons. I would to reduce the blank space between every button and its title in order to be closer to it.

[image]

```
 #ui.r
     library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    shinyUI( dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(
      title="Styling Download Button"
      ),
        dashboardSidebar(

          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("rightcolor",h5("Left"), value = "#00B2EE")),
          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("overlapcolor",h5("Overlap"), value = "#7CCD7C")),
          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("leftcolor",h5("Right"), value = "#FFFACD")),


        ),
        dashboardBody()

    ))
    #server.r
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `div` elements in which the titles are displayed. One way to do this is by adding the `style` argument to the `h5` function. If you reduce the `margin` to 0 pixels by adding `style='margin: 0px'` you get the result that you want (you can also use: `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, etc.).

If you want to adapt other Shiny widgets you can always wrap them in a `div` and adapt them with the `style` argument (example: `div(style='margin: 0px; padding: 15px;', selectInput(...))`). Information on other `div` arguments can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

**Your example**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(colourpicker)

# Create ui
ui <- shinyUI( dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Styling Download Button"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("rightcolor",h5("Left", style='margin: 0px;'), value = "#00B2EE")),
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("overlapcolor",h5("Overlap", style='margin: 0px;'), value = "#7CCD7C")),
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 115px;",colourInput("leftcolor",h5("Right", style='margin: 0px;'), value = "#FFFACD"))),
  dashboardBody()
))

# Create Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```